# using $scope inside event - google maps api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

I am trying to use scope inside this function but it seems to not working. Where should I put the argument $scope.

Thank you

Here is the structure of the code I put the main lines that reflect the structure :

```
myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','Fact', function($scope,Fact) {
   $scope.myFunc = function() {

      Fact.init(beamNumber,function(){
         polygonsBeam[ list.length - 1- i].addListener('click',function(e) {
            console.log($scope.db)
            $scope.db = 20
            console.log(list[list.length - 1 - polygonsBeam.indexOf(this)]);
         });
      });
   };
}]);
```

Comment: What's the context? Is this inside some controller? If so, are you injecting $scope into it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes it is inside a controller

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope','Fact', function($scope,Fact) {

...

Comment: I think I did inject

Comment: Then the $scope object should be part of the closure and thus accessible. When you say it's "not working", what do you mean? Is your click function not being called at all? Is it being called but it's not doing what you expect?

Comment: I edited the code in the question

Comment: it perfectly works (even the front-end) when I put the line with scope.db outside the event, one line before for ex. The console.log works even if the line with scope is inside the event but I do not see ant changes on my front end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what Fact.init is doing, but if you see your console.log but $scope.db doesn't seem to be updated, try:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
   $scope.db = 20
})
```

From https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in AngularJS from outside of
>   the AngularJS framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It worked. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Happy to help you! Please accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: Actually, what if I want to use a global variable inside my function that is not declared in the event ?
$scope.db = myglobalVariable

Comment: If it's a global variable you can use anywhere you want.